# Find components which are using GTK+ 2.x

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

When excecuting my application, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I'm receiving this after an update of some dependencies in the project so it seems that there are some parts of the code that are still pointing to some components using the previous version.

My question is: Is there a way to know which components are using *GTK+ 2.x*? Maybe using some debugging flag? This is legacy code so it is very hard to just follow header files.

Comment: Try `ldd path_to_binary`.

Comment: Good catch, Unfortunately it only shows dependencies to Gtk+ 3. I will do it recursively on some libraries to see if I can find something with this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, run `ldd` on all your binaries. Alternatively, did you forget to rebuild some of them when you did upgrade to GTK+ 3?

Comment: Actually yes, it was OpenCV. I rebuilt it again without GTK and now it works